# Rails: using gsub to find and make links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a text area called `body` in a model. I'd like to change every image to a link to that image. I've got this method which is supposed to do that but it doesn't seem to work. It breaks at each image.

```
def get_images_in(body)
  body_with_links = body.gsub( %r{http://[^\s<]+} ) do |url|
    if url[/(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/]
      "<a href='#{url}' target='_blank'><img src='#{url}' /></a>"
    end
  end
  return body_with_links
end
```

Any ideas? Thank-you!

**UPDATE**

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/txnash/9c8457f93c1ea9489faf) a link to a gist with sample body text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, you don't need to use a `return` statement in ruby.  Ruby will return the last thing by default.  In your case, this is the string returned from the `gsub`:

```
def wrap_image_with_link(body)
  body.gsub( %r{http://[^\s<]+} ) do |url|
    if url[/(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/]
      "<a href='#{url}' target='_blank'><img src='#{url}' /></a>"
    end
  end
end
```

This still isn't quite right.  I would then focus my initial regular expression on the `img` tag:

```
def wrap_image_with_link(body)
  body.gsub(/\<img.*src\=['"](.*)['"].*\/\>/) do |url|
    "<a href='#{url}' target='_blank'><img src='#{url}' /></a>"
  end
end
```

Rails has a couple helpers to clean this up.

```
def wrap_images_with_links(body)
  body.gsub(/\<img.*src\=['"](.*)['"].*\/\>/) do    
    link_to(image_tag($1), $1, :target => '_blank')
  end
end
```

You probably want to make the reg ex case insensitive:

```
def wrap_images_with_links(body)
  body.gsub(/.*\<img.*src\=['"](.*)['"].*\/\>/i) do    
    link_to(image_tag($1), $1, :target => '_blank')
  end
end
```

So `gsub`, as opposed to `sub`, changes every instance of matched reg-ex, so need to tweak the reg ex slightly to accommodate more explicit matches:

```
def wrap_images_with_links(body)
  body.gsub(/\<img[\s\w"=]+src\=['"](http[s]?:\/\/[\w.\/]+)['"]\s?[\/]?\>/i) do    
    link_to(image_tag($1), $1, :target => '_blank')
  end
end
```

Depending on the complexities of your urls, you might need to tweak the reg-ex to support `?` or characters other than white space, but this work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts so far. And yeah, I want it to be the same link: it's going to function like a zoom feature.

Comment: I have never used the block version of gsub, so let me figure that out.

Comment: @emm be sure to check out the last implementation.  It should work for you.  Based on how your img tags are formed, you can tweak the reg ex if it's not working for you as is.

Comment: So close! Thanks again. It works well except for the fact that it makes the link something like `http://localhost:3000/share/%3Cimg%20alt=%22%22%20src=%22http://advantplus.com.au/graphs/1306graph1.png%22%3E`. Using `$1` gives me a different (and still wrong) link: `http://localhost:3000/share/194`. If you've any other ideas then that'd be great, if not thanks again!

Comment: @emm Ok, one more attempt.  Feel free to post a gist of some sample body text, and we can give you a better expression.

Comment: Thanks so much yet again. I'll update the question with a gist now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33881/discussion-between-matt-dressel-and-emm)